# How Redirect "ip-111-11-111-11.privatedns.ws" to my domain name?

Tags: duplicates

I have duplicate address link in google search, how can redirect all of "https://ip-111-11-111-11.privatedns.ws/person.html" to my domain name?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what web server you're using. In general, you're looking to perform a 301 redirect.

- In nginx, this is done [using the Rewrite module](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/):

  ```
  server { 
      ...
      rewrite ^/person.html$ http://www.domain2.com/ permanent;
      ....
  }
  ```
- In Apache, this is done [using Rewrite Engine/Rewrite Rule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html):

  ```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule   ^/person.html  http://www.domain2.com/~$1  [L,R=301]
  ```